# Programmatically set Timestamper plugin "Enabled for all Pipeline builds" option

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to set Timestamper plugin "Enabled for all Pipeline builds" option programmatically (upon Jenkins installation)?

Comment: Solved by using CASC: 

    unclassified:
      timestamper:
        allPipelines: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Groovy init scripts with something like:

```
import hudson.plugins.*

instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

tsconfig = instance.getDescriptorByType(timestamper.TimestamperConfig)

tsconfig.setAllPipelines(true)

tsconfig.save()
```

See: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/groovy-hook-scripts/

And: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/timestamper/index.html?hudson/plugins/timestamper/api/TimestamperAPI.html